# How to pass a single literal tilde (in runtimepath) as pattern to substitute() in VimScript?

Tags: command-line, vim

I'm trying to replace the default `runtimepath` (aka `rtp`) in Vim using VimScript's [`substitute()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#substitute%28%29) during startup. I cannot use the `.vimrc` because the value I am setting is not available inside `.vimrc`. However, it seems that Vim complains about every attempt at passing `~` as the pattern (second parameter) to `substitute()` or ends up doing nothing.

How can I tell Vim to match and subsequently replace the tilde? Roughly what I want to do is this:

```
vim -c 'let &rtp = substitute(&rtp, "\\~", "/absolute/path", "g")'
```

Turns out `\~` gives me: `E33: No previous substitute regular expression` (although this is the pattern, *not* the replacement). But with the above `\\~` on the command line, although Vim doesn't give me an error, I also don't see any change in th value of `runtimepath`.

**Note:** I am appending `-c 'set rtp'` to the above command line so Vim shows me the value immediately.

Any alternative ways of **replacing** all instances of the `~` in the `runtimepath` variable in VimScript are acceptable, too.

Comment: You explained the means quite well but you totally forgot to explain your actual goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about you but here, `&rtp` doesn't contain a single tilde: all the filepaths are absolute: `/home/romainl/.vim/something`.

```
let aaa = substitute(&rtp, "/home/romainl", "~", "g")
```

turns all the relevant filepaths into `~/.vim/something`.

```
let bbb = substitute(aaa, "\\~", "/home/romainl", "g")
```

turns all the `~/.vim/something` back into `/home/romainl/.vim/something`.

Comment: What are you using to show it? When I say `set rtp`, which is *one* command to show it, I see a tilde.

Comment: The output of `:set rtp` and `:echo &rtp` are different. You have tildes in the first but paths are expanded in the second. You are simply trying to substitute tildes in a string that doesn't contain any tilde. If you want `runtimepath` to point somewhere else than your  `$HOME` you'll need to substitute `/home/username`, not `~`. If you want to make it a generic plugin, you'll need to come up with a generic cross-platform pattern.